# Ruby Sinatra Compile Error : Server handler (thin,puma,reel,HTTP,webrick) not found. (RuntimeError)

Tags: ruby, web-applications, rubygems, webserver, sinatra

I'm new to Ruby Sinatra, I tried to build a simple web application with Sinatra with the following code:

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'sinatra'

get '/firstapp' do
    "Welcome to my first Sinatra App !"
end
```

when I tried to run it with the command "ruby file.rb" on windows command prompt, an error occured:

```
C:/Ruby30-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/sinatra-2.1.0/lib/sinatra/base.rb:1755:in `detect_rack_handler': Server handler (thin,puma,reel,HTTP,webrick) not found. (RuntimeError)                                             
from C:/Ruby30-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/sinatra-2.1.0/lib/sinatra/base.rb:1493:in `run!'                                                                                                                       
from C:/Ruby30-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/sinatra-2.1.0/lib/sinatra/main.rb:45:in `block in <module:Sinatra>'
```

When I installed sinatra, I forgot to set the path to C:(ruby install directory)\bin. I have set the path after installing sinatra

I have no idea what happened. Can someone help me with this?

Comment: it looks like Rack is not able to find a webserver.  Try `gem install thin` as recommended in the [Sinatra intro guide](http://sinatrarb.com/intro.html).

Answer (score 6):

install these last one gem using

```sh
$ gem install thin
$ gem install puma
$ gem install reel
$ gem install http
$ gem install webrick
```

work for me

Comment: Thanks. I used webrick, which is the only one that can be installed in a clean alpine Docker image. The others require some additional tools.

Comment: we can choose puma or webbrick as web server

Answer (score 5):

I encountered this problem when using Gemfile to manage my gems, if that is the case for you, rather than use `gem install` like @yaya-hc suggested, you can add them to your Gemfile

```
gem thin
gem puma
gem reel
gem http
gem webrick
```

then run `bundle install` and try again.

Comment: No good advice - this would add 5 app servers to your app's dependencies. Only add one of these, not all.

Answer (score 0):

The previous answers are correct but the below add works fine for me in Gemfile

use single quote ''

```
gem 'thin'
gem 'puma'
gem 'reel'
gem 'http'
gem 'webrick'
gem 'falcon'
```

Comment: Why on earth would you add all the different servers to the gemfile?